# Get elements inside a jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to access elements created dynamically in a jQuery DataTable.
Consider the code below:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var tableref = $('#myTable').DataTable({ "pageLength": 10 });
  for (var k=0; k<15; k++) {
    tableref.row.add(['<div id="myDiv' + k + '">'+k+'</div>']).draw();
    console.log(document.getElementById('myDiv'+k));
  }

});
```

Since the page size is set to 10, I can only access the first 10 divs. You can see that output of the console for the next 5 elements is null.

[fiddle demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Ly2n2jhk/3/)

Why does it happen? and how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I guess it's because you set the "pageLength" to 10, this way you'll don't have the (11-15) rows injected into the table for your data injection. You could try to create the rows it dynamically using DOM and add data after this.

Comment: How about Richard's answer? I'm not sure what you exactly mean.. Can you update the code?

Comment: The question is, what do you really want to achieve by doing this? Adding new rows to your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want get all elements of your table you can use `rows().nodes()`, returns a list of tr elements that have been generated.

read for more information http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7454/fngetnodes-only-returning-visible-nodes

In your Example ....

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var tableref = $('#myTable').DataTable({ "pageLength": 10 });
   for (var k=0; k<15; k++) {
      tableref.row.add(['<div id="myDiv' + k + '">'+k+'</div>']).draw();
      //console.log(document.getElementById('myDiv'+k));//Return 10 divs
   }

  var aTR = tableref.rows().nodes();

  for (var i = 0; i < aTR.length; i++) {

       console.log($(aTR[i]).find('div')); //return 20 divs

  }

});
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/22/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the data of a datatables object, you should not iterate over the rows, but over the data property.

For reference, check out this page:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/data()

Comment: Thanks Richard. `tableref.data()[k]` gives `["<div id="myDivk">k</div>"]` which I'm not sure is exactly what I want. How do I get the div itself?